# How to replace the missing year in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have another scenario, to replace the missing year and the corresponding  columns with zeros.
My dataframe looks like this,

```
Year   Churn_Count  Churn_Rate  Customer_Count                                        
2008       1071.0    0.800149             4114
2012          0.0    0.000000                6
2013        233.0    0.174075              824
2014        101.0    0.075458              410
```

I need to fill the missing year in between 2008 to 2014 ,

for example, 
2009,2010, 2011 is missing how to fill these year in between and corresponding columns with zeros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set_index` + `reindex` + `reset_index`:

```
df.set_index('Year').reindex(
   np.arange(df.Year.min(), df.Year.max() + 1), fill_value=0
).reset_index()

   Year  Churn_Count  Churn_Rate  Customer_Count
0  2008       1071.0    0.800149            4114
1  2009          0.0    0.000000               0
2  2010          0.0    0.000000               0
3  2011          0.0    0.000000               0
4  2012          0.0    0.000000               6
5  2013        233.0    0.174075             824
6  2014        101.0    0.075458             410
```